# Подсчёт количество mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица вида:

```
Order  | unit
______________
Order1 | Unit1

Order1 | Unit2

Order2 | unit1

Order3 | unit1

Order3 | unit2

Order3 | unit3
```

---

Результат, который нужно получить:

```
Order  | count_order | unit
____________________________
Order1 |      2      | Unit1

Order1 |      2      | Unit2

Order2 |      1      | unit1

Order3 |      3      | unit1

Order3 |      3      | unit2

Order3 |      3      | unit3
```

Как написать такой запрос?

Comment: и какова логика такого результата? И каков смысл вообще такого результата?

Comment: Это пример таблицы, сама таблица не на три колонки. Логика такова, что остальные строки  из таблицы тоже нужны и они потом дополнительно обрабатываются.

Comment: Подсчёт предполагается вести по количеству повторений заказ

Comment: А потом результат где будет обрабатываться? Могу предложить вариант `select \`order\`, count(order) as count_order, GROUP_CONCAT(\`unit\`) as unit FROM \`table\` GROUP BY \`order\`` . Где в поле `unit` будут перечислены через запятую для каждого `Order`... и в коде можно будет их разбить на массив

Comment: Результат будет обработан в excel. В принципе в нем можно решить эту задачу формулой счетесли(а:а;а:а). Но на 500 тыс строк ему от этой формулы тяжело если сделать даже так счетесли ($а$1:$а$500000;А1)

Comment: Странная выборка вам нужна но.....`SELECT t1.\`Order\`, (
 SELECT COUNT(t2.\`Order\`) 
 FROM \`table\` t2 
 WHERE t1.\`Order\` = t2.\`Order\`
 ) count_order, t1.\`unit\`
FROM \`table\` t1
ORDER BY \`Order\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно заджойнить таблицу саму на себя.
Поля для скорости лучше индексировать.

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    COUNT(t2.Order) AS cnt
FROM orders AS t1
JOIN orders AS t2
    ON t2.Order = t1.Order
GROUP BY t1.Order, t1.unit;
```